# Склонение названий мессенджеров и магазинов

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, названия

Скажите, пожалуйста, склоняются ли названия мессенджеров и магазинов? Например, в гипермаркете "Глобус" объявляют: "В "Глобус" вы можете приобрести...", а про мессенджер "Телеграм" пишут: "В Телеграм можно прочитать..."
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Название в кавычках является несогласованным приложением и не склоняется.

**Несогласованное приложение** — это название книги, журнала, магазина, фильма, предприятия, заключенное в кавычки.

В предложении изменяется по падежам **родовое слово**, а несогласованное приложение стоит в начальной форме (в именительном падеже) и не изменяется:
*в романе "Война и мир", в магазине "Детский мир", **в гипермаркете "Глобус"***.

Если родового слова в предложении нет, то по падежам изменяется само приложение:
*в "Войне и мире", в "Детском мире", **в "Глобусе".***

[Несогласованные приложения](https://books.google.ee/books?id=x1rSDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=lhtVlD9qlj&sig=ACfU3U1Vn7obc57bhDQrQF2TpxfOrOXjzA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx5bm7vaXqAhUi4aYKHZ01D0QQ6AEwFnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&f=false)

*Женя не удивилась неприлично жестким срокам — уже успела привыкнуть, что в «Глобусе» с сотрудниками не церемонятся* (А. и С. Литвиновы).
*Начинать работать в «Глобусе» ему пришлось с нуля — предыдущий составитель не оставил преемнику никаких материалов* (В. Кречетов).